# Core Data fetching data of one to many relationship

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, one-to-many

I'm a noob of Core Data. I have two entities Venue and Concert and two relationships concerts (from Venue to Concert) and venues (From Concerts to Venue). What I want to do is basically retrieve all the concerts for a venue that are contained between two dates (startDate-endDate).

```
NSPredicate *concertsToShow = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL concerts.startDate <= %@ AND concerts.endDate >= %@",startDate,endDate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]).managedObjectContext;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Venue" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    [request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"concerts", nil]];
    [request setPredicate:concertsToShow];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *concerts = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    return concerts;
```

When the code is run I got the following exception:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate (null)'*

I tried to put also parenthesis on the predicate but then it says that it cannot parse the predicate.

I ended up using a subquery

```
NSPredicate *concertsToShow = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(concerts, $i, $i.startDate BETWEEN {%@,%@}).@count>0",startDate,endDate];
```

The problem is that it performs a filtering only on the venues: it retrieves only the venues that have a concert which date is contained between startDate and endDate but the concerts associated are not filtered. What I want to achieve is to have this filtering PLUS a filtering on the concerts.
So for example I have two Venues with Concerts associated (Only date shown in the example):
"Irish Pub" ->> (01-04-2013, 02-04-2013,03-04-2013,04-04-2013)
"English Pub" ->> (05-04-2013)

If the startDate and endDate of my predicate are respectively 02-04-2013 and 04-04-2013
The result should be:

"Irish Pub" ->> (02-04-2013,03-04-2013,04-04-2013)

Comment: Well, your problem is clear: the predicate is null?? I don't think you have to go to this much trouble, you should be able to make a predicate that adds your constraints easily..

Comment: Any Idea why the predicate is null??

Answer (score 0):

As **Rob** mentioned, your error message says you have nil predicate.

so put the log and check predicated value before making Request.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL concerts.startDate <= %@ AND concerts.endDate >= %@",startDate,endDate];
NSLog(@"my predicate is :%@",predicate);
```

also for good practices I would suggest,always do this way

```
if(predicate!=nil){
  //now make request here
}
```

let me know if you need more help in this.

Comment: I would add a logging breakpoint and simply put in: po predicate. But yes, that's the idea!